# Is there any practical use of redefining Math.constructor in JavaScript/ActionScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, constructor, ecmascript-5, jscript

The Math object does not have a prototype property, but does have a constructor property. Is there any case in which redefining the constructor would be useful?

Comment: `Math.constructor === Object // true` ... `Math.constructor` is identical to `Object`, so `Math.constructor("foo")` is identical to `Object("foo")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#Description) says:

> Unlike the other global objects, Math is not a constructor. **All properties and methods** of Math are **static**.

In other languages, when a class is static, you can directly use its properties and methods without creating an instance of that class ( an object ). If Math constructor is used, there is no native type to support the object, unlike with the primitive types: Number, String, Boolean. They can be converted to objects with their wrappers.

Furthermore it is a bad practice to extend a root object. If in the future new functionality is implemented in the environment and the code don't have fail-safety check for this, it will override the native one.

My personal opinion is that you do not constructor, nor prototype - you can define your own mathematical functions. The Math object is here just to present a standard functions, and give programmers the leverage not to define `Pi` or `E`, for example. And probably user defined mathematical function will be several times slower than the built-in.

Comment: So if the properties and methods of Math are static, what is the danger of extending it by defining a custom prototype and constructor?

Comment: For the prototype - maybe there will be in the future, who knows; in the future the standard may define something new, integral or something. But I don't see the point of the constructor - there is no math type to support an object created by Math.constructor().

Answer (score 6):

The `Math` object (precisely: the object referred to by the initial value of the `Math` property of the ECMAScript Global Object) does *not* have a `constructor` property, see the [ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262%20edition%205.1,%20June%202011.pdf), section 15.8 "The Math Object".  Therefore,

```
Math.hasOwnProperty("constructor")
```

returns `false` (in conforming implementations of ECMAScript Ed. 3 and later).

The `Math` object *inherits* a `constructor` property through the prototype chain from its prototype, which is "the standard built-in Object prototype 
object (15.2.4)" (ibid.), which is the same as initially referred to by the `Object.prototype` property.  The latter object provides several useful properties, such as `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` (see above).  So it makes sense that the prototype chain of the `Math` object is not empty instead.

That the `Math` object also inherits `Object.prototype.constructor` is merely a side-effect of that unconditional inheritance in ECMAScript implementations as (with the exception of implementations of the Edition 4 proposal, and perhaps of future Editions) properties do not have a suitable visibility modifier to prevent that (like `private` in several class-based languages).  And, of course, the constructor of `Object` instances, which inherit from the same prototype, is the object referred to by the initial value of the `Object` property of the Global Object.  So `Object.prototype.constructor` must reflect that.  Therefore, the result of evaluating

```
Math.constructor === Object
```

is `true`.

Comment: So how is it that 
    Math.constructor === Object 
is true, while 
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Math) === Math.constructor()
is false?

Comment: @PaulSweatte that makes no sense. When is `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` *ever* equal to `x.constructor` (or `x.constructor()`) under any normal circumstances?

Comment: @PaulSweatte maybe you meant to check `Object.getPrototypeOf(Math) === Math.constructor.prototype`?

Answer (score 5):

*All* objects have a `constructor` property, which indicates the constructor that created the object.

Even `({}).constructor` returns `Object()`.

Comment: Please change it to "usually". You could `delete Object.prototype.constructor`. Also, the `constructor` property often is missing/wrong when prototypes are set with `Constructor.prototype = {...}`.

Comment: @Bergi `delete Object.prototype.constructor` is not a good idea.  However, you can create an object that has an empty prototype chain, and therefore inherits no property. Such an object is useful as data container as there is little chance of any property name collisions. Since Edition 5 this is possible without resorting to the proprietary `__proto__` property. For example, `Object.create(null).constructor` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Math does not have its *own* "constructor" property.  It inherits "constructor" from Object.prototype, just like it inherits "toString", "hasOwnProperty" and all of the other properties of Object.prototype.

For Math, "construct" probably has very little utility. It is just there as a consequence of how JavaScript inheritance works,.

Comment: Math does not have a prototype, so how does it inherit?

Comment: @PaulSweatte: `Math`'s prototype is `Object`.

Comment: Math.prototype returns undefined.

Comment: @PaulSweatte Check `Math.__proto__`, or use `Object.getPrototypeOf(Math)`. Both are identical to `Object`.

Comment: So Math.__proto__ and Object.getPrototypeOf(Math) are equal to Math.constructor().

Comment: @PaulSweatte no, they are not equal. `Math.__proto__` is a plain old object. `Math.constructor` is `Object`, so `Math.constructor()` returns another plain old object that is equivalent but *not equal to* `Math.__proto__`.

Answer (score 2):

`Math` object "inherits" from `Object` (meaning `Math.__proto__ === Object.prototype`)

The `Math` object is nothing more to any JavaScript programmer than a "special" but simple `Object` with methods attached whose implementation and construction is automatic and hidden.

`Object.prototype` defines a `.constructor` field (actually any function assigns itself to its own prototype's constructor, see *ex1*)

*ex1 (a little bit of a detour)*:

```
function xxx() { }
// then:
xxx.prototype.constructor === xxx; // true
// since xxx is a function:
xxx.constructor === Function.prototype.constructor; // true
// and as such:
xxx.constructor === Function; // true
```

***As such when you use `Math.constructor`, it's just looking up the `Math` object's prototypical chain like this (...well kind of):***

1. `Math` --> `Math.hasOwnProperty('constructor')`**`=== false`**
2. *NOT FOUND MOVE NEXT*
3. `Math.__proto__` --> `Math.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('constructor')`**`=== true`**
4. *FOUND, RETURN:* `Math.__proto__.constructor`

***so basically:***

```
Math.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor; // true
// and as such:
Math.constructor === Object; // true
// and as stated at the top:
Math.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // true
```

hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Math object in JavaScript tries to simulate the static Math behavior in other popular programming languages (for example Java). Since this can only be simulated in JavaScript, and all Objects have prototype and constructor properties by default, my guess is that the developers have just forgotten to set the constructor property to `undefined`, by executing explicitly something like `Math.constructor = undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

In a situation in which you need to generate a conversion table without polluting the global scope, this would be useful. For example:

```
Math.constructor = function() {
  var i = 0, unicode = {}, zero_padding = "0000", max = 9999;
  //Loop through code points
  while (i < max) {
    //Convert decimal to hex value, find the character, then pad zeroes to the codepoint
    Math.constructor[String.fromCharCode(parseInt(i, 16))] = ("u" + zero_padding + i).substr(-4);
    i = i + 1;
    }    
  }
```

Invoke the constructor to populate it as such:

```
Math.constructor();

Math.constructor["a"]
```

Another use would be to extend the properties and methods to define  primitives for a graph library:

```
root(arg,index)     "index-th" root of argument. Example: root(x,6) sixth root of x, root[tan(x),4] fourth root of the tangent of x.
sqrt()  Square root of argument (number or expression inside the parentheses). Equivalent to root(argument,2)
cbrt()  Cube root of argument. Equivalent to root(argument,3)
logn(arg,base)  Logarithm base-base of arg.
ln()    Natural logarithm of argument (base-E logarithm of argument where E is Euler's constant)
lg()    Logarithm base-10 of argument, equivalent to logn(argument,10).
lb()    Logarithm base-2 of argument.
exp()   Exponential Function E to the power of argument, equivalent to E^argument
sin()   Sine of argument
cos()   Cosine
tan()   Tangent
cot()   Cotangent
sec()   Secant of argument, equiv. to 1/cos(arg).
csc()   Cosecant, equiv. to 1/sin(arg).
asin()  Arc sine
acos()  Arc cosine
atan()  Arc tangent
acot()  Arc cotangent
asec()  Arc secant, inverse secant.
acsc()  Arc cosecant, inverse cosecant.
sinh()  Hyperbolic sine, Sinus hyperbolicus
cosh()  Hyperbolic cosine, Cosinus hyperbolicus
tanh()  Hyperbolic tangent, Tangens hyperbolicus
coth()  Hyperbolic cotangent, Cotangens hyperbolicus
sech()  Hyperbolic secant, Secans hyperbolicus.
csch()  Hyperbolic cosecant, Cosecans hyperbolicus.
asinh()     Area sine, Area sinus hyperbolicus, inverse sinh().
acosh()     Area cosine, Area cosinus hyperbolicus, inverse cosh().
atanh()     Area tangent, Area tangens hyperbolicus, inverse tanh().
acoth()     Area cotangent, Area cotangens hyperbolicus, inverse cotanh().
asech()     Area- secant, Area secans hyperbolicus, inverse sech().
acsch()     Area- cosecant, Area cosecans hyperbolicus, inverse csch().
gaussd(x,mean,sigma)    Gaussian distribution ("Bell Curve"). gaussd(x,0,1), by the way, is the special case "Normal distribution density with mean-value=0, standard-deviation=1".
min(arg1,arg2)  Returns the lesser of the two arguments
max(arg1,arg2)  Returns the greater of the two arguments
round()     Rounds argument up or down to the closest integer
floor()     Rounds arg down.
ceil()  Rounds arg up.
abs() or | |    Absolute value of argument. Example: 2abs(sin[x]) or alternatively 2|sin(x)| .
sgn()   Sign Function.
```

```
rand    Random number between 0 und 1. Example:
pi*rand*sin(x) or even Pirandsin(x) .
E   Euler's constant 2.718281828459045...
LN2     Natural logarithm of 2, is 0.6931471805599453...
LN10    Natural logarithm of 10, is 2.302585092994046...
LOG2E   Base-2 logarithm of E (E: see above), is 1.4426950408889633...
LOG10E  Base-10 logarithmus of E, is 0.4342944819032518...
PHI     Golden Ratio 1.61803398874989...
PI  3.141592653589793...
SQRT1_2     Square root of 1/2, is 0.7071067811865476...
SQRT2   Square root of 2, is 1.4142135623730951...
```

**References**

- [Augmenting JavaScript Core Objects](http://www.sitepoint.com/augmenting-javascript-core-objects/)
- [Walter Zorn: Online Function Grapher](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/grapher/grapher_e.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    Math.prototype=Math;
    Math.prototype.rand=function(min,max){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min+1))+min)
    }

    var o=[];
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++)o.push(Math.rand(-1,1));
    alert(o.join(", "))
    </script>
```

Of coarse you could also just do:

```
Math.rand=function(min,max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min+1))+min)
}
```

The reason Math doesn't come with its own prototype like Array and String is because it isn't a function but rather an object. Since you can use new `String()` and new `Array()` you are also able to use `String.prototype` and `Array.prototype`.

The same goes for `Object, Function, Number, Date, RegExp and even Boolean`. However any defined function will be assigned a prototype property and will inherit from Function and whatever else in the chain it has to inherit from.

If you want to treat `Math` like a function, all you have to do is override the variable with a function. That way `Math.constructor` will not return Object when called since it would actually be linked to your user-defined function that created it.

You can make a copy of the native object first then toss it to one of the prototype properties of your overriding function, or use encapsulation so only your new Math function can access the native methods. Not sure what else can be said on the subject.

The opening question is kind of pointless. **Math.constructor will return Object and will be the same as calling Object directly. The only difference would be if you changed the constructor.**

Why would you want to change the constructor anyways?

The `Math` object is perfectly fine the way it is. If we expected it to inherit something from somewhere, what would we expect "`this`" to point to anyways? If you can come up with an answer to that question, you will have something with a purpose you can code.

Comment: Why would you want to change the constructor is the crux of the question? [Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) touched on something years ago, and how could that idea be improved upon?

Comment: @PaulSweatte who says you have to change the constructor unless you are changing the prototype? And why would you want to change the prototype of a static object? To extend it? Well, since it's static, you can simply extend it by appending methods/properties of your own. Why make it complex? And, by the way, I couldn't understand where does Resig's idea come here - it was to do with 'stealing built-in functionality'?

Comment: The idea used built-in functionality from Math to enhance Array, so the question is could that be done in a better way?

Comment: `Math.prototype = Math` makes no sense. `Math` is not a constructor, so giving it a prototype property does nothing. You have simply overwritten `Math`'s `rand` property, and added a self-referencing `prototype` property that serves no purpose.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this answer that I almost do not know where to begin. Functions *are* objects. The `prototype` property of a `Function` instance is only used implicitly upon object construction; it is _not_ proof that an object has a non-empty prototype chain, nor is the lack of it proof of the opposite; the `Math` object certainly has one, that is why it can *inherit* a `constructor` property. And so on. The answer says the question is "kind of pointless". Well, the answer completely misses the point of the question.