# Why is Math.prototype undefined?

Tags: javascript, math, prototype

I must be missing something here, because `Math.prototype` is [undefined for me](http://jsfiddle.net/R3GqT/). Why is this? I tried to do something like this:

```
Math.prototype.randomRange = function(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

But instead had to do something like this:

```
Math.randomRange = function(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

That doesn't feel right, though. Is it just me or should I be doing this another way? I apologize if this is a silly or duplicate question, but I couldn't find anything by searching (exactly two questions turn up when I search SO for "Math.prototype", which is kind of weird).

Comment: Please read this [good advice](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Modifying_prototypes_of_builtin_objects)

Comment: @dystroy: I am well aware of the caveats surrounding extending built-in objects. I appreciate the link anyhow, though. *--edit--* You appear to be referring to extending *prototypes*, which I'm not doing.

Comment: Simple: function objects (constructors) have prototypes, `Math` is not a constructor function. `typeof Math` returns `"object"`, but `typeof Array` returns `"function"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Math` functions are like class-level functions in other OO languages. There's no prototype object on the constructor; nobody (I know of) uses the constructor anyway.  (What would you do with a `Math` instance?)

*edit* — it's been pointed out in a comment (and it never occurred to me to check I guess) that `Math` isn't a function anyway. Type `Math()` in your browser console and you'll get an error.

Comment: So does that mean doing `Math.randomRange` is fine, then?

Comment: It's fine as long as your code won't be reused. A common law is to NOT extend standard objects and classes.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville yes that's fine, other than the general caveats about making changes to the built-in objects.

Comment: Aha, thanks Pointy. Accepting when I can. @dystroy: No worries, I'm well aware of that.

Comment: Yes, `Math.randomRange` is perfectly fine. Although I would recommend putting your own extensions in a separate namespace, such as `MyMath.randomRange`. You never know if the next version of JavaScript would introduce a new method with that exact name.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville The worst problem is modifying the prototype of Object. However, adding new properties to constructors is not likely to cause a problem, unless you use some code that also uses the same static method (Math.randomRange) in a different way

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: Naturally, I'm planning on surrounding this with an `if(typeof Math.randomRange === "undefined")` to avoid conflicts like that.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville even if you do do that your code could mysteriously break some day in the future as you don't know what interface a `Math.randomRange` could have in the future and if it would even behave the same way so I would go with using its own name space.

Comment: "The constructor" is nonexistent! `Math` is an object, not a function.

Comment: @doug65536 indeed; I confess I never checked and just assumed it was a "parallel" companion to `String()`, `Boolean()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because Math is a static object, not a constructor. It will throw an error if you call `new Math()`

Comment: `Math` is not a constructor, `new Math()` is nonsense and throws `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

`Math` in JavaScript is the equivalent of a static class in other languages. It has no prototype or constructor (the equivalent of, say, writing a class in Java with all static methods and only a private constructor).

For further information, see this StackOverflow question: [Is there any practical use of redefining Math.constructor in JavaScript/ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339334/is-there-any-practical-use-of-redefining-math-constructor-in-javascript-actionsc)

Specifically, the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10431309/1403635